# how to get back the modified INOUT parameter in postgres

Tags: postgresql, trigger, functions, cast

I have two functions with a similar signature, lets say:

```
CREATE FUNCTION func1(INOUT new "My_Table") AS $$ ... $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION func2(INOUT new "My_Table") AS $$ ... $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I call both of these functions from a `BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGER` where the parameter is the row being updated. I want to give the row to the function as an input but subsequently modify it inside the function (therefore the `INOUT`).

I call the first function as:

```
SELECT * FROM func1(NEW) INTO NEW;
```

Which works just fine.

However, I can't make it work with the second function because the type of NEW is no longer of "My_Table" but it is "record" and I am unable to cast it.

```
SELECT * FROM func1(NEW) INTO NEW;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM func1(NEW::"My_Table") INTO NEW;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM func1(CAST(NEW AS "My_Table")) INTO NEW;
```

gives

```
ERROR:  42846: cannot cast type record to "My_Table"
```

How can I do this please?

Comment: `SELECT ... INTO somename;` creates new table `somename`: [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-selectinto.html). Is it really what you want? If you want to assign a query result to the plpgsql variables you should to use `SELECT * INTO NEW FROM func1(NEW);` or probably just `NEW := func1(NEW);`.

Comment: `NEW := func1(NEW);` works! `SELECT * INTO NEW FROM func1(NEW);` gives `ERROR:  42846: cannot cast type record`

Comment: also a solution I found is to cast to the `text` first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the two working solutions:

```
NEW := func1(NEW);
```

or first cast the `record` to `text`:

```
SELECT * FROM func1(NEW::text::"My_Table") INTO NEW;
```